# Code::Blocks does not parse header #define

Tags: c, ide, codeblocks

Code::Blocks has a surprising shortcoming — its editor is unable to parse multiple source files correctly to do #ifdef / #ifndef style code path highlighting correctly. It only works for the file where you define macros directly in but not on any other related project file. For example:

MyHeader.h

```
#define MRAA__
```

MyProgram.c

```
#include "MyHeader.h"
#ifndef MRAA__
#define FOO() Foo_Bcm2835()
#else 
#define FOO() Foo_Mraa()
#endif
```

The #ifndef MRAA__ evaluates as true although you have defined MRAA__ in your header file. Now the **compiler** handles this just fine but visually in editor it's wrong.

Yes, you can turn off the graying-out entirely but it's pretty handy feature to have around... Is there really no plugin / patch to fix this functionality? I could find people complaining about it in 2012.

[image: Editor showing inactive code incorrectly]

Comment: What compiler??

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a coding issue, but an issue with your IDE?

Comment: @ryyker I had the macros for FOO() swapped but otherwise the (incorrect) #ifndef behavior is as stated.

Comment: @ChrisTurner IDE, I even did bold the part about compiler being a-okay :-p

Comment: After re-reading the question, (and running similar code in my `Code::Blocks` environment) I see the problem you are referring to, i.e. in the editor, `Code::Blocks` greys out the wrong logical branch.  Have you registered this problem _[HERE](http://forums.codeblocks.org/)_

Comment: How would the editor know which header to parse.  There might be multiple variants of the header selected by different compilation options with different results.  It would surprise me if it does it.

Comment: @ryyker Someone did this way back in 2012: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16576.0 and there's a bug registered for it since 2014: https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/100/ Not that I couldn't refresh it a bit..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I think this a a problem with the C/C++ lexer commonly in use by the Code::Blocks IDE.  I have seen this problem for several versions.  (In fact, I cannot recall _not_ seeing this since starting to use Code::Blocks years ago)  I just did another test this morning to confirm locally defined symbols are highlighted correctly, while symbols defined in a header file are not.

Comment: This post is a rare example of one that would benefit from an embedded  image to show exactly what you are talking about.  I admit I did not read it carefully the first time, and because the text of your post does not show the greying out of the "true" path of the #ifndef directive, I missed the point.

Comment: @ryyker so have extra 1001 words.

Comment: I was editing a similar illustration of the problem when you posted yours.  If you like, I will remove mine, as it is not really an answer, just a clarification of the problem.

Comment: @ryyker Nah. They're aware of the issue apparently, the previous bug was unrelated, this one's spot on: https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/541/ although that's still "not going to be fixed soon" but at least someone's paying attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

*This post is not intended as an answer, just a clarification.
An image is included to highlight the problem discussed in the 
original post, and hopefully draw the attention of Code::Blocks 
developers to an* *[existing bug registered at least 5 years ago](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16576.0)* - *[and similar](https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/541/)*.

As of today I am not aware of any patches or fixes or revisions to address this problem...

The following image was captured in Code::Blocks version 13.12 in a
C project, and *illustrates* the OP syntax highlighting problem. (Note: 
OP version is even newer: 16.01)

Although Code::Blocks (and GCC) correctly executes only the "true"
branches of an #ifdef (or #ifndef) directive, syntax highlighting is reveresed for 
symbols defined in any file other than the one it is being used.

For example, MRAA__ is defined in a file other than this .c file,
and when it is used here, the "true" branch of the #ifdef is greyed out.
But for ABCD__, which is defined in this file, the "false" branch is greyed out.

[image]

Comment: A partial solution is to use Eclipse.. If you can put up with either ancient apt version or don't mind muddling through the installation process (yes, installer on linux!). For the heretics there's the Visual Studio linux plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Please whatever problem you may be experiencing here and for anyone who comes along with such a similar problem please consider what compiler you are using in your code blocks. It can save a life somewhere

Comment: The compiler is irrelevant since this is an editor bug.